# Let $X$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ such that $\sum (x_i)^2 $ converges...

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ denote the subset $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ consisting of all sequences $(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $\displaystyle \sum x_i^2$ converges.

a) Show that if $\mathbf{x,y} \in X$, then $\displaystyle\sum{|x_iy_i|}$ converges.

I am not even sure how to get started. Can you tell me where to look?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: Also you can show that its bounded and increasing sequence of partial sums thus sequence of partial sums converges

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Robert Israel's hint, use $$|x_iy_i| \leq \frac{x_i^2+y_i^2}{2},$$ which is a simple consequence of the trivial inequality $(|x_i|-|y_i|)^2 \geq 0$, and also a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you. That helps quite a bit.